How to deploy some files last with gatsby-plugin-s3?
I'm using gatsby-plugin-s3 (https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/@sfeinste/gatsby-plugin-s3/) and have 10,000+ files uploaded during the deploy step.
I'm receiving errors from Google Search Console regularly that files are not found, but when I inspect the URLs they are appearing fine. I suspect the reason why this is happening is due to Google bot crawling during an upload and the main index files are uploaded earlier than others.
Regardless if this is the reason why or not, I would like to set an order for deployment to improve the Google Bot's findings, and of course my end user's experience.
